# Is it possible to put a spreadsheet in Thunderbird templates that will calculate?

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, thunderbird, templates

For various reasons, I am using Thunderbird as my main email client.  I'd love to be able to set up a template that will automatically calculate/extend out data for the purposes of quotes, etc.

I am using the table currently, but I hate that I have to manually extend out and do all the calculations either on a calculator or through another program.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You need a spreadsheet template that does what? Embeds into thunderbird?

Comment: Seems like you should be doing all the heavy lifting in Excel then copying and pasting what you need into an email body. There is no way (that I know of) to embed a working Excel object into the body of an email (outlook, gmail, thunderbird, or otherwise).

Comment: I just tried it in Office 2010, Outlook accepts an Excel object with a paste-special.  I wouldn't *use* the functionality though, it's asking for trouble for privacy and compatibility.  Especially if you're sending stuff like quotes.  You don't want the customer to see the math under your quote.

Answer (score 1):

This Thunderbird add-on that I've listed, helped resolve this issue for me:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dafizilla-table2clipboard/